# GET/POST requests Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I learning currently Google Drive API and developing program in Qt C + + (using OAuth2), so I need to build queries, but I'm not found how to do it.

For example, if I make a request - https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN, everything is working OK - I get the reply.

Question is: how to make a SIMILAR request for the Google Drive?

1) how can I get a list of folders and files

2) how can I create a folder / file 
etc.

For example, in a POST request
"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v1/files&title=pets&mimeType=application/vnd.google-apps.folder"

I get

"error": {
  "errors": [{
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}

how to get a list of folders and files, for example, etc., I do not understand

Any opinions/examples are welcome!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the Drive API doesn't let you list folders or files. The only way to retrieve a file is by integrating with the Drive web UI or showing a [Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open) to your user (web app only).

Once you have a File ID, you can simply send an authorized GET request to the [drive.files.get endpoint](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/get):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v1/files/id
```

To [insert a file (or a folder)](https://developers.google.com/drive/folder), the File's metadata is to be included in the request body, not as query parameter:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v1/files
Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}
Content-Type: application/json
...
{
  "title": "pets",
  "parentsCollection": [{"id":"0ADK06pfg"}]
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}
```

In the example above, the `mimeType` specifies that the resource being inserted is a folder. Change the `mimeType` to your application MIME type when inserting a file.

Comment: is this still true? that you cannot list files?

Comment: It is still true with v1, but v2 has the list endpoint that you can use.

Comment: For some reason when I try to list files using the oauth2playground http://code.google.com/oauthplayground/ provided by google, the API would always return an empty array of items despite the fact that I have tons of files inside google drive. Do you know why that may be the case?

Comment: If using the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope, the list endpoint will only return files that the app (e.g OAuth Playground) has created or have been opened with it. To learn more about the different scope, have a look at this [page](https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes)

Comment: No, You can list all the files and folders. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list

Answer (score 0):

You should use google docs API for that

> [Retrieving a list of collections - Google Documents List API version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#retrieving_a_list_of_collections)

In OAuth 2.0 Playground just select both Documents List and Google Drive
And you will get full list of operations:

```
List FolderContent
GET https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/{folderResouceId}/contents
```

Don't forget to add the `?v=3` query parameter to the Document list URI or adding

```
GData-Version: 3.0
```

header, otherwise it will return `"Invalid request URI"`.

Answer (score 0):

You advise you to look at the google drive api reference docs in

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list

i succeeded using many api functions following link above and using curl. But actually i recommend you trying to do http requests with a tool like postman. Anyway after getting access code following the steps link below

[list google drive files with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593022/list-google-drive-files-with-curl)

try to make following command in the command line.

```
curl -H 'GData-Version: 3.0' -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
        https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=$100
```