# Google Drive Api - Get Folder Paths

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I'm currently using the Google Drive API to get a list of folders (or subfolders).  In order to do this I use the following URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1234folderid1234/children?key=1234APIKEY1234&q=mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder';
```

This returns back a list of the folders as expected, however, I also need either the name of the folder or the full folder path.  This information is not returned with this call.  Is there a way to get the list of folders with the associated folder name or path in one call?

Thanks

Comment: This might answer your question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345381/get-post-requests-google-drive-api

Comment: It looks like this question deals with v1 whereas I'm dealing with v2.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Use [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) (which gives full file resources)
2. Amend your query to add the parent id you want to search in.

   `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 'folderId' in parents`

Comment: Folders don't appear to show up on my response (regular files do, though). Any idea why that might be?

Comment: I had the same issue, using a query helped me: 
`FileList result = service.files().list().setQ("'myname@domain.com' in owners").execute();`

Comment: Another good query filter in this regard `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late, but the best solution to solve this problem is to use a recursive function that searches for the last folder parent. There is a NodeJS solution with GD API v3, but the reasoning is the same for every language and GD API version.

```
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
const rootFolderID = 'TheHighestFolderIDOfYourGoogleDriveAccount';
function getFileOrFolderCompletePath(fileOrFolderID, pathList = [], callback){
    let pathList = [];

    if (fileOrFolderID !== rootFolderID){
        drive.files.get({
            fileId: fileID,
            fields: 'id, parents',
        }, (error, response) => {
            if (!error){
                pathList.push(response.data.parents[0])
                pathList = pathList.reverse();
                getFileOrFolderCompletePath(response.data.parents[0], pathList, callback);
            }
        });
    }else{
        callback(pathList.join('/'))
    }
}
```

You should call:

```
getFileOrFolderCompletePath('fileIDtoGetThePath', [], (path) => {
    console.log(path); //It will log: 'path/to/your/file'
})
```