# list google drive files with curl

Tags: curl, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get the list of files on Google Drive with curl, but OAuth 2 is getting the best of me.

Here are some of the things I tried:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files
```

Where $token is a 460 character string I got using:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin
```

and this upload [script](https://gist.github.com/deanet/3427090#comment-1258499) (which works great). This is the error I received:

```
 {
  "error": {
   "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "authError",
      "message": "Invalid Credentials",
      "locationType": "header",
      "location": "Authorization"
    }
   ],
   "code": 401,
   "message": "Invalid Credentials"
  }
 }
```

Also tried:

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?key=apiKey
```

Error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

And:

```
curl -H "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=${token}" "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files"
```

Error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

I had little success with both the JavaScript and PHP client libraries, both seem optimized for the situation where the user provides log/pass in order to authorize the app. What I need is a way to list the files from a single account, every time.

Answer (score 15):

I just spent like 30 minutes to figure this out myself for accessing contacts API and redid the steps for drive API and documented them for future reference. There are 5 steps and the first 4 are one time setup.

**Step 1**: Create new OAuth2 credentials

[image: Create API Manager > Credentials > OAuth Client ID]

[image: Application type = Other, Name = curl-client]

[image]

Note down the `client ID` and `client secret`.

**Step 2**: Request authorization with drive as scope.

Using the `client ID` and `https://docs.google.com/feeds` as `scope`, construct the below curl command:

```
$ curl -d "client_id=413437979384-05efiod756k5hp2eji5tsn2lmlg0qslc.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https://docs.google.com/feeds" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code
{
  "device_code" : "KRYU-NTVW4/qi6ysOpK2AtsmtZz4MB9LAthlYGGgAepxpBnGQLvhqo",
  "user_code" : "KRYU-NTVW",
  "verification_url" : "https://www.google.com/device",
  "expires_in" : 1800,
  "interval" : 5
}
```

Copy the `user_code`.

**Step 3**: Authorize the request.

Visit the verification URL https://www.google.com/device and enter the copied code.

[image: Paste the code and press Next]

[image: Press Allow]

**Step 4**: Obtain `access_token`.

Add the `device_code` obtained from the auth request to the `client ID` and `client secret` and construct the below curl command:

```
$ curl -d "client_id=413437979384-05efiod756k5hp2eji5tsn2lmlg0qslc.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=0zWNribRJ4PcYWH-rDkCpCcm&grant_type=http://oauth.net/grant_type/device/1.0&code=KRYU-NTVW4/qi6ysOpK2AtsmtZz4MB9LAthlYGGgAepxpBnGQLvhqo" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
{
 "access_token": "ya29.kgKW4Z4IDqK7lCjUQw-u5VT2uAx19MtgdoKeAC9ikKYGwKh7Nh46pY8nQsANQ5lRwA",
 "token_type": "Bearer",
 "expires_in": 3600,
 "refresh_token": "1/qinFVaMPYvhWtUtmjb1qCpnQt48XyvQhB_ILZJ4H1Uw"
}
```

We now have the required `access_token`, save it and use it with all the drive REST API requests.

**Step 5**: Drive API request.

```
$ curl -H 'GData-Version: 3.0' -H 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.kgKW4Z4IDqK7lCjUQw-u5VT2uAx19MtgdoKeAC9ikKYGwKh7Nh46pY8nQsANQ5lRwA' https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
...
```

Comment: but the token has expiration, can I renew it without verifying the code on the browser?

Comment: Great answer, Thank you. I was able to replicate the process. I am also, however, curious on how to refresh the `access_token`s when they expire. Any help on that?

Comment: One of the best answers on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 7):

For future googlers:

If you want to save yourself an afternoon of pain, forget google's doumentation and head over [here](http://www.visualab.org/index.php/using-google-rest-api-for-analytics)

The gist of it, since I know stackoverflow prefers quoting the content to linking:

First, get your client ID in Google Developer Console for OAuth2. This will require to fill in the OAuth consent screen and after testing, you will have to get your domain verified. (Google will lead you in the process...)

In your browser:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&client_id=1234567890.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Allow the access, of course, and copy the code which should look like 4/v6xr77ewYqjkslsdUOKwAzu

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'code=4/v6xr77ewYqjkslsdUOKwAzu&client_id=1234567890.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=xywzxywzxywzxywzxywz&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code' https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

You’ll get a JSON like this one:

```
{
  "access_token" : "ya29.AHES6Zkjhkjhahskjhskkskjh",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "refresh_token" : "1/HH9E7k5D0jakjhsd7askdjh7899a8sd989"
}
```

If you curl:

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=ya29.AHES6Zkjhkjhahskjhskkskjh'
```

you’ll get something like:

```
{
 "issued_to": "562211803675.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "audience": "562211803675.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics",
 "expires_in": 3556
}
```

Done

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts?access_token=ya29.AHES6Zkjhkjhahskjhskkskjh
```

*Renew the token*

You have to use the “refresh_token” received previously

```
curl -d "client_id=562211803675.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=ZQxoOBGbvMGnZOYUrVIDXrgl&refresh_token=1/HH9E7k5D0jakjhsd7askdjh7899a8sd989&grant_type=refresh_token" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

and you’ll get a new access_token.

Comment: But this is analytics ... does it work the same way for drive.files? I wasn't able to get an access token for that scope using this description, yet.

Comment: By the way, as 20 July 2022, the source link is dead. That is the reason why Stack Overflow prefers quoting content over just linking it, as a precaution in case that happens.